# Parse Woocommerce Webhook (JSON)

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, woocommerce, webhooks

Wommcommerce fires a Webhook when a product is updated or an order is placed. I'm trying to catch this Webhook with a Google Apps Script (GAS), published as a WebApp. What I'm finally trying to achieve is to write incoming orders into a Google Spreadsheet.

I'm having trouble to get the right (or at least some) data out of these webhooks. I tried different ways to write the data into a sheet, but the only thing I ever caught in the sheet was 'undefined'. Honestly I  don't know how to handle the JSON data. My testfunction is now:

```
function doPost(e){ 
  var doc =     DocumentApp.openById('myDocId');
  var jstring = Utilities.jsonStringify(e);
  doc.appendParagraph(jstring);
}
```

When firing the webhook (order updated) I get the following output in the document:

> {"parameter":{},"contextPath":"","contentLength":1523,"queryString":null,"parameters":{},"postData":"FileUpload"}

Obviously not parsed at all, but all I tried (e.g. getContentText()) didn't work. The Webhook-Log in Woocommerce tells me that this was sent:

> {"product":{"title":"testprodukt","id":136,"created_at":"2015-10-06T13:15:38Z","updated_at":"2015-10-09T15:19:04Z","type":"simple","status":"publish","downloadable":true,"virtual":true,"permalink":"http://MYDOMAIN/produkt/testprodukt/","sku":"","price":"5.00","regular_price":"5.00","sale_price":null,"price_html":"€5,00","taxable":false,"tax_status":"taxable","tax_class":"","managing_stock":false,"stock_quantity":"","in_stock":true,"backorders_allowed":false,"backordered":false,"sold_individually":false,"purchaseable":true,"featured":false,"visible":true,"catalog_visibility":"visible","on_sale":false,"product_url":"","button_text":"","weight":null,"dimensions":{"length":"","width":"","height":"","unit":"cm"},"shipping_required":false,"shipping_taxable":true,"shipping_class":"","shipping_class_id":null,"description":"
>
> somedescription
>
> n","short_description":"","reviews_allowed":false,"average_rating":"0.00","rating_count":0,"related_ids":[],"upsell_ids":[],"cross_sell_ids":[],"parent_id":0,"categories":[],"tags":[],"images":[{"id":0,"created_at":"2015-10-09T15:19:05Z","updated_at":"2015-10-09T15:19:05Z","src":"http://MYDOMAIN/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/placeholder.png","title":"Platzhalter","alt":"Platzhalter","position":0}],"featured_src":false,"attributes":[],"downloads":[],"download_limit":0,"download_expiry":0,"download_type":"","purchase_note":"","total_sales":7,"variations":[],"parent":[]}}

I'm looking for a hint, links, examples, a push in the right direction how to get the data out the webhook.

Comment: Hi, do you have any idea where to find some sample data from webhooks? I have to implement webhooks of my client's eshop so I can't "create new product" or "new order" and test it manually

Comment: @did you used google spreasheet library for that ? How can I implement same feature for my WordPress site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in e.postData.content

Also use JSON.parse instead of Utilities.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the help here from Riel and at [plus.google](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769) I figured it out. Here is my code as an example, maybe it helps:

```
function doPost(request) {     

var json = request.postData.getDataAsString(); 
var obj = JSON.parse(json);     


// getting some of the Woocommerce data just as an example
// Hook was fired after order.created
var id = obj.order.id;
var orderNumber = obj.order.order_number;
var payMethod = obj.order.payment_details.method_title;    


// write data in a document, not useful, but straightforward for testing   

var doc =     DocumentApp.openById('myDocumentId');
doc.appendParagraph("Id: " + id);
doc.appendParagraph("orderNumber: " + orderNumber);
doc.appendParagraph("payMethod: " + payMethod);

}
```

Result should look like this:

> Id: 171
>
> orderNumber: 171
>
> payMethod: Per Nachnahme